# Crashing of my system 2

Tags: mesh

Hi guys good to be here.  Am new to blender and am trying to learn it ASAP.  Pls my blender keeps crashing when ever am at shader editor and my changes doesn't affect my mesh in the shader. Pls how do I fix these. My system specs is Intel core i7 2620M CPU @ 2.70 GHz.  8gig ram, 
54 - bit Operating system.  Windows 7. Thanks

Comment: The relevant part here is likely your GPU and graphics driver. Update your graphics driver and check if that resolves the problem. Also make sure that your system fulfills the minimum requirements to run Blender (https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/).

Comment: I had a similar issue of constant crashes, I can confirm that updating my GPU drivers fixed the issue, so as rjg recommended try that first.